# Where are minecraft languages stored and how can I add a new one?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

Where are minecraft languages stored?

I want to add a new language such a pirate speech except for making it my own. I already have my .lang file ready, but do not know what to do with it.

Where can I place this file so it is read by ALL compatable minecraft versions and I can use it?

Also, where can I store (IF POSSIBLE) a copy of

```
credits.txt
end.txt
splashes.txt
```

So it can be in the same language?

Comment: This language file would be used in a texture pack, not a language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are writing a mod that will add language (therefore people with the mod will be able to choose this language), then all you need is to add your lang file as any other.

If you add lang files into this folder in your mod:

```
src/main/resources/assets/yourmodname/lang/
```

You will add those entries to existing lang default one (so you can add names for new items for example)

However If you add your lang file into minecraft directory, you will overwrite existing one (Like that YOURS will be used with higher priority than original one, when SAME NAME used - otherwise you will add another language), then the path will be:

```
src/main/resources/assets/minecraft/lang/
```

The texts you want also include are in

```
src/main/resources/assets/minecraft/texts/
```

However after removing of the mod, you will still have original Minecraft language files.

You can look at more in-depth tutorial for lang files by BedrockMiner: http://bedrockminer.jimdo.com/modding-tutorials/basic-modding-1-7/language-file/

---

If you dont want to compile your own mod for this, then all you need is to rewrite original MC file (and it is stored in same directory as above when you open minecraft's jar with winrar, except that you need to omit `/src/main/`.

PS: For example IndustrialCraft2 has Pirate language added, you can open it's JAR with WinRar and look at it where and how it is done. (But be aware that there is something like copyright and you just cannot grab their file and use it on your own project without asking the authors)

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is create language support in resource packs as you can see in maps like The Heist.

In the resource pack go to assets/minecraft/lang folder. Create files like EN_US.lang with content like:

```
language.name=English
language.region=US
language.code=en_US

container.dropper=Dopfer
container.furnace=New funace
container.enchant=Book stealer
container.crafting=

deathScreen.respawn=Restart!
deathScreen.title=Game Over
```

You cannot add new languages without mods. You have to change existing ones.

Hope it helped :)

Comment: Will this overwrite the original language?

Comment: Yes, just take something like frace.