# Where are Minecraft language files?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I'm looking for Minecraft language files to a resourcepack, but I only found the English US one.
Where are the another ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265102/where-are-minecraft-languages-stored-and-how-can-i-add-a-new-one) question here.

> What you can do is create language support in resource packs as you can see in maps like The Heist.
>
> In the resource pack go to assets/minecraft/lang folder. Create files like EN_US.lang with content like:

```
language.name=English
language.region=US
language.code=en_US

container.dropper=Dopfer
container.furnace=New funace
container.enchant=Book stealer
container.crafting=

deathScreen.respawn=Restart!
deathScreen.title=Game Over
```

> You cannot add new languages without mods. You have to change existing ones.

Comment: Thank you

But I tried to do it with LOLCAT and didn't work


`"language.name": "LOLCAT",
  "language.region": "Kingdom of Cats",
  "language.code": "lol_AA" `


Is something wrong with it?

Comment: @Lukaz-835 I expect that your formatting was incorrect - `.json` files are notorious for that. [This link](https://pastebin.com/raw/K1YvFkjR) is to what the original `en_us.json` is; **yours should be EXACTLY like this** _except for changes in the parentheses following the colon at the end of each line_. **Make sure that it is in the right directory, too.** Assuming your .minecraft folder is in the default location (`AppData`), the language `.json` file should be in `C:\Users\You\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\resourcepacks\ResourcePackName\assets\minecraft\lang`.

Comment: @Lukaz-835 One other thing - I saw you change the `"language.code"`. You might not want to do that because that might be tied to the file name. I don't know for sure how it works, but that probably also contributed to it not working for you.

Comment: @Lukaz-835 I just tested - as long as you do everything like I said it should work. Good luck! :)

Comment: I'm editing LOLCAT language, and the file's name/language code is lol_AA according to Minecraft Wiki, so I don't think this is really the problem (I also tried to remove the language.things in the file like I did in another language but still doesn't work)